# Do low-rep editors check back edit reviews?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, statistics

When reviewing edits one can choose to single-handedly approve or reject a suggestion.
This is done by making another edit on top of it.

When I use this feature I try to be thorough in my edit messages, detailing everything I've done from the title to the tags. The idea is that, should the editor come back to the review, they can see everything they missed when editing and learn from it.

Since there's no notification from approvals or rejections (even with edits) this requires them to manually go to the edit review page. This seems it would severely reduce the visibility of the review result to low-rep editors. Simple edit rejections also become invisible.

Can we have some numbers on how much low-rep editors check back on their reviews?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing if there's a spike right around edit ban approval ratios.

Comment: Does getting a rejected edit not result in a "Hey, this got rejected last time" type message the next time you try to edit like you get with flags? I thought it did though now I can't recall seeing one personally.

Comment: If they're interested in the +2 rep I imagine they're at least checking to see if the edit eventually got accepted.

Comment: @BSMP Yep, but they can do that simply looking at their rep notifications after a while.

Comment: A link to the rejection will show up above the edit box when they start to make their next suggestion.

Comment: I did check them if that helps. I even checked the accepted edits to see how many negative comments there were on these. I appreciated manual review comments.

Comment: Low-rep editors notice when they see a +2 on their rep/notification icon. When I was <2K I always kept a tab open on the review, periodically refreshing to see who was approving/rejecting my edits and why. I presume not everyone does that though.

Comment: Personally, I keep an eye on edits that I worry will be rejected for being too big. I'm more invested in those because they take longer to do. If I'm just doing some grammar corrections I don't tend to check back.

Comment: I check every one of my edits. While the majority get accepted, I still like to see 1) if any big meta names I know rejected 2) if any big meta names I know accepted 3) if the author was involved and 4) if there were any reject votes. I find it useful to tweak my edit habits. I check for the meta names mainly because I have a higher chance of understanding how they review based on discussions I've seen them take part in on Meta.

Comment: Judging just from these comments, it seems like <2k users are vigilant.  Unfortunately, this is the MSO selection bias, and I'm not so sure the average active SO user is so vigilant.

Comment: As a low-rep (<2k) user with a fair number of edits, I wasn't even aware that there was a place to go check.

Comment: I did periodically check my Suggested Edits tab to see if I'd had something rejected. The main thing that I learned was not to add info from the OP because even specifying that it came from them in the comments didn't prevent reviewers from rejecting it.

Comment: @g.rocket You haven't gotten any rejected so you wouldn't have gotten any review links either.

Comment: @BSMP That's just not true.  On my main SO account, I have had 6/39 edits rejected, including recently [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16345529) (which I don't understand at all why it was rejected).

Comment: @g.rocket - My mistake. Did the system not tell you you'd gotten rejections? (As for that edit, if you make code changes to answers that aren't correcting errors it will get rejected.)

Comment: @BSMP It didn't tell me anything.  I only just realized it got rejected when I tried to find my list of edits.

Comment: I'm not necessarily a great editor but I can't think of a single time I've looked for feedback on an edit I made. Maybe I've looked out of curiosity some time later, but never otherwise.

Comment: I always kept an eye on my edits.  The +2 rep was an easy-in to see if the edit was unanimously approved or not. When there was no rep change, I was always curious to know if it was stagnant or why it was rejected. This helped me differentiate between the type of edits that **1)** were good, **2)** were questionable, **3)** would always age away, **4)** were bad, and **5)** required Meta discussion for clarification.

Comment: Oops, I would wager I only adjust the edit description about 40% of the time. Usually just to correct poor grammar/spelling used by the original editor...